# SQL error , unknow column on clause?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to **LEFT JOIN** this table field, but it gives me the title error. 
The problem starts when I add the left join query line. I guess it should be somewhere else.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT questions.* , user_profile.first_name , user_profile.uIMG , user_profile.mid_name 
,user_profile.last_name , q_categories.cat_title , qreports.u_ID

FROM questions , user_profile , q_categories
LEFT JOIN qreports ON  questions.qID = qreports.q_ID
WHERE questions.uID=user_profile.UID AND questions.qID= 8
AND questions.cat_ID=q_categories.cat_ID
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The problem is 1) Formatting 2) Old style `,` syntax instead of JOIN

Comment: i dun understand , what do you mean ?

Comment: the `SELECT <something>, <somethingelse>` syntax the comma between the values acts as a JOIN.

Comment: The query looks truncated _AND questi_ - is that the entire query. What is the exact error message?

Comment: yes , but i need a left join so if there's no report the code runs !!

Comment: @PaulF , i've just redited the code , it was transacted a mistake , anyway the error is , unknown column questions.qid on clause

Comment: Then see lad2025 comment - you are mixing new & old style joins

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting and style is old and also not a proper joining. try this query and adjust the query (because the given query is not complete)

```
SELECT 
q.*,u.first_name , u.uIMG ,u.mid_name ,u.last_name,qc.cat_title,qr.u_ID 
FROM questions AS q
LEFT JOIN user_profile AS u ON q.uID=u.UID
LEFT JOIN q_categories AS qc ON q.catID=qc.catID
LEFT JOIN qreports AS qr ON q.qID=qr.qID
WHERE 1
```

In `WHERE` condition you can use any condition if you want